# Power produced by expanding gas

Tags: thermodynamics

Calculate power produced by CO2 gas pressure driven 100% efficient turboexpander. Inlet pressure is 48 megapascals and inlet temperature is 425 kelvin and inlet flow rate is 3886 kilograms per second and inlet enthalpy is 4900 kilojoules per kilogram. Outlet pressure is 10 megapascals and the outlet temperature is 295 kelvin and the outlet flow rate is 3886 kilograms per second and the outlet enthalpy is 15 kilojoules per kilogram.

To determine the solution I have down the following calculation which am not sure is correct because I am not sure the enthalpy drop accounts completely for the power of the expanding gas driving the turbine since the enthalpy tables I used are only provided at constant pressure and only a function of change in temperature. Please advise if my solution is correct and actually accounts for everything. Thanks

Enthalpy Drop = 4900 - 15 = 4885 kilojoules per kilogram Power = (3886 kg/s) * (4885 kjoules/kg) Power = 18,975,610 KJ/sec * 1000 w/KJ = 18,975,610,000 watts

Therefore, the power produced by the CO2 gas pressure-driven turboexpander is approximately 18,975,610,000 watts.

This doesnt seem right to me. Are my methodology, assumptions, and calc correct?

Comment: Do you insist on accuracy of 7 valid digits? // Good practice is starting with symbolic algebraic expressions and keeping it this way until all is ready to plug in literal numbers with units. It helps in focusing on principles, mistakes are easier to spot, orientation is improved, Q/A is reusable and has bigger  permanent value. 

You may find useful  [formatting mathematical/chemical expressions/formulas](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88).

Comment: I have noticed you have reposted the closed question, what is against the site policy and this will be closed as well. 
Address the reasons why the original one was closed and ask for reopening.